# Detect design mode in "OnApplyTemplate" method - custom control

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, custom-controls

Here is how my `OnApplyTemplate` looks:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool) return;

            this.partTextBox = this.GetTemplateChild(PartTextBox) as TextBox;
            this.partButton = this.GetTemplateChild(PartButton) as Button;

            if (this.partTextBox == null || this.partButton == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Template part(s) not available");
            }

            this.partTextBox.LostFocus += this.OnTextBoxLostFocus;
            this.partButton.Click += this.OnButtonClick;

            if (this.DataProvider == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("DataProvider wasn't specified");
            }
```

Second line where I check for IsInDesignTool gives me error saying that I can't access internal class "DesignerProperties" here.

Basically what happens is when I drag my control from toolbar into view in design it throws exception because DataProvider not specified. So, I need to disable this code for desing time.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's another class somewhere called DesignerProperties which is interfering with the one you really want to use.  How about:

```
if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool) return;
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! I checked - there was 4! possible DesignerProperties!

Answer (score 0):

I think correct code is,

```
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignTool(this)) return;
```