# XAML/C#: Page/Property Style Changing Efficiency

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently working on a WPF project, and I am at an aspect of the program where I don't know how to create the solution efficiently.

Problem:
In my program, I plan on implementing UI versions (Dark mode, Light mode, etc.). Basically just UI color preferences. However, I am unsure of the best way in which I can use the other UI features.

So far, I have set up styles for each UI preferences in the APP.XAML, based on individual properties, such as textboxes and rectangles, and put the general style within the individual pages to be shown.

The UI changes need to be kept within the same SHOWN XAML file so that events can be implemented. I believe it needs to be done by using APP.XAML (which I have already been using this). However, what would be the best way in showing the UI changes? Should I be creating a whole page style? Changing each property individually based on styles? Or is there some better way in completing the UI changes efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: avoid asking questions which are primarily opinion-based. BTW the keyword here is **THEME**.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based. This is about finding the fastest way to complete a task in XAML. Each answer can be tested, and give a measurable value, comparable from other answers, rather than a question like, "Do you like java or c++ better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to some of the questions and statements:

- The standard templates (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603437/563088) use Themes so that would be a logical first step to follow
- It might be easier to maintain separate files with the templates and colors in resource dictionaries although templates will have to be in the Generic.xaml
- Do not use events, use Commands and Bindings. If you need to use events, do not hook them up in XAML but hook them up in the OnApplyTemplate of the controls. That way templates can be swapped out and templates are no longer forced to provide specific controls/events as the OnApplyTemplate can search for a control and skip it if it isn't found.
- As for switching: from experience I found it easier to define multiple color/brush/resource sets in separate files. Give these colors and brushes the same names (e.g. HighlightBrush, ButtonBorder or CheckBoxCheckGlyph). Depending on the theme you load a different resources file. the templates would simply refer to these resource names (using DynamicResource if you want to enable live switching or StaticResource for switching on restart of the window/app)

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is super helpful! On "OnApplyTemplate", are you referencing events that would be changing the style of one's xaml property, or an event such as a button click?

Comment: When you create a Custom Control (not a UserControl!) you also create a template in the generic.xaml file for that control. In the C# code of the control you can override the OnApplyTemplate and try and find controls and their events. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054705/detect-design-mode-in-onapplytemplate-method-custom-control